# Swift @propertyWrapper 'Self' refers to the enclosing struct/class instead of property wrapper struct

Tags: swift, property-wrapper

I coded a simple property wrapper in Swift and I tried to use `Self` and `self` to refer to the property wrapper struct/class `Reference<T>` in the `projectedValue` property:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
class Reference<T> {
    private var value: T
    
    init(wrappedValue: T) { value = wrappedValue }
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }
    
    var projectedValue: Self { self }
}
```

But it appears that `Self` is not referring to the type `Reference<T>`. For instance if I declare such property in a struct and then use the `projectedValue`:

```
struct Test {
    @Reference var value: Int = 1
}

let t = Test()
let ref = t.$value
```

The variable `ref` is of type `Test` instead of `Reference<T>`. This code does not compile and results in a segmentation fault but Xcode does not return any interactive error. To make the code work as expected I must declare it like this:

```swift
var projectedValue: Reference<T> { self }
```

This feels very weird, is it intended behavior or not? I checked Apple documentation but this behavior is not documented.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get a segfault, which is also weird... Why not do `var projectedValue: Reference<T> { self }`?

Comment: Only reason is that `Self` is very convenient and I use this pattern everywhere in my code.

Comment: This bug seems to have been reported multiple times: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12609 and https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11152 for example.

Comment: Oh I was wrong the code does not compile either for me. However no interactive error are shown by Xcode and Xcode successfully infers the variable type.